# Accessing Powershell COM Object in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, com-interop, comobject

I need to convert a Powershell script to C#.

The Powershell script accesses the Windows Deployment Service COM Object:

```
$wdsObject = New-Object -ComObject WdsMgmt.WdsManager
$wdsServer = $wdsObject.getWdsServer("Localhost")
[...]
```

Is it possible to access these COM Objects in C#?

I couldn't find the corresponding COM Object reference in Visual C#.
I tried to add the `wdsmgmt.dll` from System32 as a reference in a C# project, but that didn't work. I'm quite stumped otherwise.

EDIT:

Answer to comment 1:
[Best way to access COM objects from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c-sharp)

The COM Object in question isn't listed in the references. I've looked through the list about 5 times to be sure I wouldn't miss it.
Would there be a way to make that COM Object show up in the COM references list in C#?

Answer to comment 2 (what did not work):
Trying to add wdsmgmt.dll shows the following error:

`Please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`

The file is accessible, but it doesn't seem to be a valid COM component in the eyes of C#.

A search in the registry for WdsMgmt shows that the COM Object is at least somehow present:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{CD583E47-B079-4025-A799-5F951D016D3E}`

Maybe the rephrased question would be:

How do I add a COM Object reference to C# when I know it's name in Powershell?

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c-sharp

Comment: "that didn't work": Ok, what exactly have you tried, and in what way did it not work?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have edited my question to reflect on your inputs.

Comment: I think `wdsmgmt.dll` is an MMC snap-in. It may well be that you can only access this functionality via C++. This *might* help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530729(v=VS.85).aspx  (all the code samples are in C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly mirror what PowerShell does by using `dynamic`, and creating the instance by ProgId. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3251325/8446 for example.

Comment: This was the hint that I needed to get this done! The application only compiled in x64 architecture though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [TlbImp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcwlkcominteroppart1cclienttutorialanchor1)?

> Creating a COM Class Wrapper
>
> For C# code to reference COM objects and interfaces, you need to
>   include a .NET Framework definition for the COM interfaces in your C#
>   build. The easiest way to do this is to use TlbImp.exe (Type Library
>   Importer), a command-line tool included in the .NET Framework SDK.
>   TlbImp converts a COM type library into .NET Framework metadata —
>   effectively creating a managed wrapper that can be called from any
>   managed language. .NET Framework metadata created with TlbImp can be
>   included in a C# build via the /R compiler option. If you are using
>   the Visual Studio development environment, you only need to add a
>   reference to the COM type library and the conversion is done for you
>   automatically.

Here is more information about this interop tool:

[Tlbimp.exe (Type Library Importer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)